# multiple .hover animation functions

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to combine .animate statements in the same hover function.

Basically, I have an image that, when I mouse over the div, slides out to the right while a new image slides in to replace it.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
//Set div dimensions equal to image's dimensions:
$('#image_holder').width($('#image_1').width());
$('#image_holder').height($('#image_1').height());

//tell the browser what to do when hovering on the div:

$('#image_holder').hover(function() {
//when mouse hover:
$('#image_0').animate({right: '-' + $(this).width() + 'px'}, /*duration*/360, /*ease*/'swing');    
$('#image_1').animate({right: '0px'}, /*duration*/360, /*ease*/'swing');
}, 

function() {
//when mouse out, no hover:
    $('#image_0').animate({right: '0px'}, /*duration*/360, /*ease*/'swing');  
    $('#image_1').animate({right: '-' + $(this).width() + 'px'}, /*duration*/360, /*ease*/'swing');
});
```

And my HTML is pretty simple:

```
<div id="image_holder" class="image_holder">
    <img id="image_0" class="image" src="images.png" />
    <img id="image_1" class="image" src="images_hover.png" />
</div>
```

Right now, the first image (image_0) does slide out, but the second image (image_1) does not slide in.  I have a feeling it's something simple I'm messing up...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: see my update -- it should work as you intended

Comment: I think that might be it!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XevTC/1/

Here is an update of something I think you *want* to do: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XevTC/2/ (but I could always be wrong)

---

I think this is what you intended: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XevTC/11/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This isn't quite it.  What I'm going for is for one image to slide off to the right while another image slides into its place.  In this one, the images are stacked...

Comment: @David -- remember to select an `accepted answer` if you found one :-)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Checking Neal's answer, your code seems to be working.

But, reading your question it seems like you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ewNpL/1/)?

Comment: That's not quite it, either.  I'd like the first image to collapse to the right while the second image expands to the left.  If that makes sense...